# Kendo UI Autocomplete for Angular 4 -data search triggered on enter key press

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, autocomplete

We are currently using Kendo UI autocomplete within an Angular 4 application.
At present we allow a user to enter text and the autocomplete lookup is triggered immediately on the first character entered.

We have a requirement to disable the search until the user has pressed the enter key.

Does anyone know if this is possible?

After consulting the documentation on http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dropdowns/autocomplete/  I know I can highjack the open action and prevent default or alternatively disable lookup until X characters  but, not until key press.

I'm guessing that the on blur event might be usable.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to access the actual underlying HTML input element and attach a keydown handler, then perform custom logic for preventing the built-in filtering until the Enter key is pressed, open the Popup programmatically via the toggle() method, and call the search handler on Enter:

```
ngAfterViewInit(){
  this.ac.searchbar.input.nativeElement.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
    if(e.which === 13){
      this.enterPressed = true;
      this.ac.toggle()
      this.handleFilter(e.target.value)
    } else {
      this.enterPressed = false;
    }
  });
}

handleFilter(value) {
  if(this.enterPressed){
    this.data = this.source.filter((s) => s.toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLowerCase()) !== -1); 
  } 
}

onOpen(e){
  if(!this.enterPressed){
    e.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

[EXAMPLE](http://plnkr.co/edit/znKY6zI80hntY2a9QnfW?p=preview)